# Exception while running Ho_import profile magento

Tags: magento-1.9, product, php, importexport, avs-fastsimpleimport

I have a Ho_import profile script that add simple products on my magento.
This mording is showing this error, no changes has made:

```
CRIT (2): Exception while running profile import_products, ran for 0.12 seconds
CRIT (2): #0 /home/user/domains/dominio.it/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/user/domains/dominio.it/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/user/domains/dominio.it/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/user/domains/dominio.it/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `mage_eav_attribute_set` AS `main_table` WHERE (entity_type_id = '4')', Array)
#4 /home/user/domains/dominio.it/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `mage_eav_attribute_set` AS `main_table` WHERE (entity_type_id = '4')', Array)
#5 /home/user/domains/dominio.it/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `mage_eav_attribute_set` AS `main_table` WHERE (entity_type_id = '4')', Array)
#6 /home/user/domains/dominio.it/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(734): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `mage_eav_attribute_set` AS `main_table` WHERE (entity_type_id = '4')', Array)
#7 /home/user/domains/dominio.it/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(521): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `mage_eav_attribute_set` AS `main_table` WHERE (entity_type_id = '4')', Array)
#8 /home/user/domains/dominio.it/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(566): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->getData()
#9 /home/user/domains/dominio.it/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(741): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#10 /home/user/domains/dominio.it/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Product.php(501): Varien_Data_Collection->getIterator()
#11 /home/user/domains/dominio.it/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Product.php(435): Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import_Entity_Product->_initAttributeSets()
#12 /home/user/domains/dominio.it/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1348): Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import_Entity_Product->__construct(Array)
#13 /home/user/domains/dominio.it/public_html/app/Mage.php(463): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('fastsimpleimport/import_entity_product', Array)
#14 /home/user/domains/dominio.it/public_html/app/code/community/AvS/FastSimpleImport/Model/Import.php(82): Mage->getModel('fastsimpleimport/import_entity_product')
#15 /home/user/domains/dominio.it/public_html/app/code/community/Ho/Import/Model/Import.php(683): AvS_FastSimpleImport_Model_Import->processProductImport('/home/user/domains/dominio.it/public_html/var/import/import_products.csv')
#16 /home/user/domains/dominio.it/public_html/app/code/community/Ho/Import/Model/Import.php(477): Ho_Import_Model_Import->_importData()
#17 /home/user/domains/dominio.it/public_html/app/code/community/Ho/Import/Model/Import.php(101): Ho_Import_Model_Import->_importMain()
#18 /home/user/domains/dominio.it/public_html/app/code/community/Ho/Import/Model/Observer.php(107): Ho_Import_Model_Import->process()
#19 (): Ho_Import_Model_Observer->process(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule)
#20 /home/user/domains/dominio.it/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(325): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#21 /home/user/domains/dominio.it/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(72): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->_processJob(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule, Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element)
#22 /home/user/domains/dominio.it/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->dispatch(Varien_Event_Observer)
#23 /home/user/domains/dominio.it/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Mage_Cron_Model_Observer, 'dispatch', Varien_Event_Observer)
#24 /home/user/domains/dominio.it/public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#25 /home/user/domains/dominio.it/public_html/cron.php(76): Mage->dispatchEvent('default')
```

What does it mean?

On mage_eav_attribute_set table there are two entity_type_id with value = 4, this is the content of the table:

```
attr.id  typeid  name           order
1        1       Default        1
2        2       Default        1
3        3       Default        1
4        4       Default        1
5        5       Default        1
6        6       Default        1
7        7       Default        1
8        8       Default        1
9        4       Customset      0
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We moved magento installation on another server, the problem is solved.